# docker container using the same volume even after running new container image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have f.e. two containers in docker

**compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: local-nginx:0.3
    ports:
      - "81:81"
    volumes_from:
      - webapp
  webapp:
    image: local-webapp:0.65
```

**webapp Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:4.3.0
...
VOLUME /www
CMD npm run some_script
```

So, what's happening, webapp container shares folder /www to nginx, and static files are serving from nginx container.
I'm starting my app with command

```
docker-compose -f compose.yml up
```

everything working fine, good. But when I want for example run application with another version of webapp **local-webapp:0.66**
I change version to 0.66 in compose.yml, stop current containers and run again

```
docker-compose -f compose.yml up
```

But, I still see the same version of webapp. when i go inside nginx container I still see the same files from previous *0.65*.  To see correct files, I must remove all containers, and then again docker-compose -f compose.yml up.

So, the question. How is this possible to configure my compose.yml file to update volume without removing all containers?

Comment: This is somewhat unclear - you're saying that *even though there is no 0.65 container in existence*, you're still seeing a volume from a 0.65 container?

Comment: container 0.65 exists, but I've changed version  in compose.yml to 0.66. Stopped containers, and run again **docker-compose -f compose.yml up** with new versions. Only after removing all containers, changes applies

Answer (score 1):

This is because [Compose preserves volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/#/preserve-volume-data-when-containers-are-created).

If you want new data, you have two options:

- don't use a volume
- remove the containers first